# Issues with lzss compression

Tags: c#

I have implemented Apples LZSS variant in C# and I seem to have issues with compressing "larger" files.

I cannot get it to reencode it to exactly the same as the source file; (Basically trying to decode then encode, and verify they are equal)

The buffer size has to be 0x400, and the dictionary size has to be 34 bytes.

This is for a game that decompresses based on these conditions, so the file has to be reencoded the same way.

The issue has nothing to do with the decompression, since I have verified the decompression does work as expected.

The project should include everything you need to test to make sure you are recreating a file.

Any help getting this to work correctly would be greatly appreciated.

(Note, the original apple source may also have this bug,  I have not tried getting it to work in C)

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
//Original source located at: https://github.com/opensource-apple/kext_tools/blob/master/compression.c
namespace LZSSTest
{

    public class LZSS
    {
        const int BufferSize = 1 << 10;
        const int DictionarySize = 34;


        public class EncodeState
        {
            public int[] lchild = new int[BufferSize + 1];
            public int[] rchild = Enumerable.Repeat(BufferSize, BufferSize + 258).ToArray();
            public int[] parent = Enumerable.Repeat(BufferSize, BufferSize + 1).ToArray();
            
            public byte[] text_buf = Enumerable.Repeat((byte)0xFF, BufferSize + DictionarySize + 1).ToArray();

            public int match_position = 0;
            public int match_length = 0;
        };

        static void insert_node(EncodeState sp, int r)
        {
            
            int cmp = 1;
            int p = BufferSize + 1 + sp.text_buf[r];
            sp.rchild[r] = sp.lchild[r] = BufferSize;
            sp.match_length = 0;
            for (; ; )
            {
                if (cmp >= 0)
                {
                    if (sp.rchild[p] != BufferSize)
                        p = sp.rchild[p];
                    else
                    {
                        sp.rchild[p] = r;
                        sp.parent[r] = p;
                        return;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (sp.lchild[p] != BufferSize)
                        p = sp.lchild[p];
                    else
                    {
                        sp.lchild[p] = r;
                        sp.parent[r] = p;
                        return;
                    }
                }
                var i = 0;
                for (i = 1; i < DictionarySize; i++)
                {
                    if ((cmp = sp.text_buf[r + i] - sp.text_buf[p + i]) != 0)
                        break;
                }
                
                
                if (i > sp.match_length)
                {
                    sp.match_position = p;
                    if ((sp.match_length = i) >= DictionarySize)
                        break;
                }
            }
            sp.parent[r] = sp.parent[p];
            sp.lchild[r] = sp.lchild[p];
            sp.rchild[r] = sp.rchild[p];
            sp.parent[sp.lchild[p]] = r;
            sp.parent[sp.rchild[p]] = r;
            if (sp.rchild[sp.parent[p]] == p)
                sp.rchild[sp.parent[p]] = r;
            else
                sp.lchild[sp.parent[p]] = r;
            sp.parent[p] = BufferSize;  /* remove p */
        }
        /* deletes node p from tree */
        static void delete_node(EncodeState sp, int p)
        {
            int q;
            if (sp.parent[p] == BufferSize)
                return;  /* not in tree */
            if (sp.rchild[p] == BufferSize)
                q = sp.lchild[p];
            else if (sp.lchild[p] == BufferSize)
                q = sp.rchild[p];
            else
            {
                q = sp.lchild[p];
                if (sp.rchild[q] != BufferSize)
                {
                    do
                    {
                        q = sp.rchild[q];
                    } while (sp.rchild[q] != BufferSize);
                    sp.rchild[sp.parent[q]] = sp.lchild[q];
                    sp.parent[sp.lchild[q]] = sp.parent[q];
                    sp.lchild[q] = sp.lchild[p];
                    sp.parent[sp.lchild[p]] = q;
                }
                sp.rchild[q] = sp.rchild[p];
                sp.parent[sp.rchild[p]] = q;
            }
            sp.parent[q] = sp.parent[p];
            if (sp.rchild[sp.parent[p]] == p)
                sp.rchild[sp.parent[p]] = q;
            else
                sp.lchild[sp.parent[p]] = q;
            sp.parent[p] = BufferSize;
        }
        public static List<byte> Compress(List<byte> input)
        {
            var output = new List<byte>();
            const int THRESHOLD = 2;
            EncodeState sp = new EncodeState();
            int i;
            byte c;
            int len, last_match_length;
            byte[] code_buf = new byte[THRESHOLD * 8 + 1];
            byte mask = 1;
            code_buf[0] = 0;
            int code_buf_ptr = 1;
            int s = 0;
            int r = BufferSize - DictionarySize;
            int inputIdx = 0;
            for (len = 0; len < DictionarySize && inputIdx < input.Count; len++)
                sp.text_buf[r + len] = input[inputIdx++];
            for (i = 1; i <= DictionarySize; i++)
                insert_node(sp, r - i);
            insert_node(sp, r);
            do
            {
                if (sp.match_length > len)
                    sp.match_length = len;
                if (sp.match_length <= THRESHOLD)
                {
                    sp.match_length = 1;  /* Not long enough match.  Send one byte. */
                    code_buf[0] |= mask;  /* 'send one byte' flag */
                    code_buf[code_buf_ptr++] = sp.text_buf[r];  /* Send uncoded. */
                }
                else
                {
                    code_buf[code_buf_ptr++] = (byte)sp.match_position;
                    var high = ((sp.match_position & 0xFF00) >> 3);
                    var low = ((sp.match_length - (THRESHOLD + 1)) & 0x1F);
                    code_buf[code_buf_ptr++] = (byte)(high | low);
                }
                if ((mask <<= 1) == 0)
                {
                    for (i = 0; i < code_buf_ptr; i++)
                    {
                        output.Add(code_buf[i]);
                    }
                    for (i = 0; i < code_buf.Length; i++)
                    {
                        code_buf[i] = 0;
                    }
                    code_buf_ptr = mask = 1;

                }
                

                last_match_length = sp.match_length;
                for (i = 0; i < last_match_length && inputIdx < input.Count; i++)
                {
                    delete_node(sp, s);    /* Delete old strings and */
                    c = input[inputIdx++];
                    sp.text_buf[s] = c;    /* read new bytes */
                    if (s < (DictionarySize - 1))
                        sp.text_buf[s + BufferSize] = c;
                    s = (s + 1) & (BufferSize - 1);
                    r = (r + 1) & (BufferSize - 1);
                    insert_node(sp, r);
                }
                while (i++ < last_match_length)
                {
                    delete_node(sp, s);
                    s = (s + 1) & (BufferSize - 1);
                    r = (r + 1) & (BufferSize - 1);
                    if ((--len) == 0)
                        insert_node(sp, r);
                }
            } while (len > 0);
            if (code_buf_ptr > 1)
            {    /* Send remaining code. */
                for (i = 0; i < code_buf_ptr; i++)
                {
                    output.Add(code_buf[i]);
                }
            }
            return output;
        }

        public static List<byte> Decompress(List<byte> input)
        {
            const int THRESHOLD = 2;
            var text_buf = new byte[BufferSize];
            int inputIdx = 0;
            var output = new List<byte>();
            int bufferIdx = BufferSize - DictionarySize; //r
            byte c = 0;
            ushort flags;


            for (int i = 0; i < BufferSize - DictionarySize; i++)
                text_buf[i] = 0x0;

            flags = 0;
            for (; ; )
            {
                if (((flags >>= 1) & 0x100) == 0)
                {
                    if (inputIdx < input.Count) c = input[inputIdx++]; else break;
                    flags = (ushort)(c | 0xFF00);  /* uses higher byte cleverly */
                }   /* to count eight */
                if ((flags & 1) > 0)
                {
                    if (inputIdx < input.Count) c = input[inputIdx++]; else break;
                    output.Add(c);
                    text_buf[bufferIdx++] = c;
                    bufferIdx &= (BufferSize - 1);
                }
                else
                {
                    int i = 0;
                    int j = 0;
                    if (inputIdx < input.Count) i = input[inputIdx++]; else break;
                    if (inputIdx < input.Count) j = input[inputIdx++]; else break;
                    i |= ((j & 0xE0) << 3);
                    j = (j & 0x1F) + THRESHOLD;
                    for (int k = 0; k <= j; k++)
                    {
                        c = text_buf[(i + k) & (BufferSize - 1)];
                        output.Add(c);
                        text_buf[bufferIdx++] = c;
                        bufferIdx &= (BufferSize - 1);
                    }
                }
            }

            return output;
        }
    }

}
```

Source:
https://github.com/knight0fdragon/LZSSTest/

Original code from apple:
https://github.com/opensource-apple/kext_tools/blob/master/compression.c

Comment: Is there any reason why you are doing this yourself and not just using a unit tested and open source library?

Comment: It is to hack a game

Comment: I don't see why that means you wouldn't be able to use a library...

Comment: Because whatever library exists may not support the specific platforms that it may pertain to.  The “why” is not relevant here, please quit focusing on that part.

Comment: The "why" is *absolutely* relevant when you're asking people to review 250 lines of non-idiomatic C#, and when others may well believe that using an existing library is a much better solution. I'd expect there to be existing libraries that are "just C#" with very vanilla target frameworks, and I'd still expect that to be the simplest approach. The fact that you haven't given any more information than "I seem to have issues with compressing larger files" isn't great either.

Comment: (For example, in this sort of thing I'd absolutely expect you to try the C code, and if the problem is that your C# code can't decompress the results of compression with large files, I'd try it both ways round - given a large file, can your C# code decompress the result of the C code, and can your C code decompress the results of the C# code. What kind of failure do you get, etc.)

Comment: I should not have to explain why I am doing something.  It goes beyond just c# and I just need a working implementation to be able to port to other devices.  If the problem could be solved with a library, I would use a library.  There is also nothing more I can really explain, which is why I included the project.  On small files, it works, on larger files it does not produce an accurate result.  There is no run time errors, only broken results.

Comment: I can decompress files fine, it is the compression that doesn’t work accurately.

Comment: No one is judging here, the comments are suggestions and trying and help. Unfortunately you have pasted a large bunch of complex code that has been hewn from another language and will require detailed debugging and forensic analysis with specs to fix the problem. Even worse the problem maybe inherent in the original code, there is no real debugging apart from a failing test so it becomes a fix my code question. I do wish you the best of luck, but i really do think an answer to this in this format is asking a bit too much

Comment: @TheGeneral every question is a “fix my code” question, and yes, I need a second pair of eyes to look and see where the algorithm is going wrong, which is why I provided a MCVE.  Not all questions on SO are going to be easy, lol.  I do this type of troubleshooting for people all the time on here, so it should not be unexpected to find somebody else to take a look at the code and point out the flaw.  It is most likely going to be something stupid that is being missed.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out

```
                 if ((--len) == 0)
                    insert_node(sp, r);
            }
        } while (len > 0);
```

should be

```
                 if ((--len) > 0)
                    insert_node(sp, r);
            }
        } while (len > 0);
```

A very simple miss on my part.

While this does solve the problem where it was creating an inaccurate compressed, it still does not reproduce an exact original file.

I am able to at least work with this for now, and this code should be able to help anybody else needing lzss in c#.